# Using Keyword: .Close or .Dispose

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection

When implementing the `using` keyword to instantiate an `IO.StreamWriter` object does that imply that `.close` is called on the object or `.dispose`? Or does it matter since once it hits the end using it is out of scope and will be garbage collected anyways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The using keyword will call `Dispose`.  However, by *convention*, `Dispose` and `Close` should always perform the exact same functionality, and be interchangable.

As such, any resource that is `IDisposable` but also provides a `Close()` method, such as `Stream` derived classes, are fine to use within a `using` block.

This is addressed in the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) explicitly: "it is important that you make the `Close` implementation identical to `Dispose`"...

The [MSDN help for IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) also suggests this: "The implementer of a class that has such a convention might choose to implement a public method with a customized name, such as Close, that calls the Dispose method."

> Or does it matter since once it hits the end using it is out of scope and will be garbage collected anyways?

It will not be garbage collected - after it is no longer in scope, and no longer referenced by any objects, it will be *eligible* for garbage collection.  This means that it will (at least if written properly), *eventually* get cleaned up, but it may not happen for a long time - including not until the program terminates.  The using block causes the resource (not the memory), such as the stream, to be closed *immediately*.

Answer (score 2):

`Using` only calls `Dispose` at the end of the scope. However, for classes such as `StreamWriter`, `Dispose` ends up calling `Close` internally.

> Or does it matter since once it hits the end using it is out of scope and will be garbage collected anyways?

This is a misconception: the whole reason for the `Using` block and the `Dispose` method is that an object is *not* garbage collected immediately at the end of the scope.